# How to populate a column in a df based on conditions in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to programming and self taught so excuse my limited knowledge.

I have a df that looks like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1= pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'Description': ['This car is german', 'This vehicle is french', 'This automobile is british', 'This car is british', 'This thing is british'], 
    'SUV?': ['Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes'],
    'Action': [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
    })
df1
```

What I would like to do is to populate the column "Action" with the string "buy" if the word 'british' is present in the column "Description" and the word "Yes" is present in the column "SUV?"

I tried to use the lambda function but I can only make it work with one of the conditions. For instance:

```py
df1["Action"] = df1['Description'].apply(lambda x: "Buy" if "british" in x else "0")
```

If someone could put on the right track I would appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [**`np.where()`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) method `import numpy as np`

```py
df1['Action'] = (np.where((df1['Description'].str.contains('british')) 
                    & (df1['SUV?'] == 'Yes'), 'Buy', ''))
print(df1)
```

With lambda approach:

```py
df1['Action'] = (df1.apply(lambda x: 'Buy' if 'british' in x["Description"] 
                    and x['SUV?'] == 'Yes' else '', axis=1))
print(df1)
```

---

```
                  Description SUV? Action
0          This car is german  Yes       
1      This vehicle is french   No       
2  This automobile is british   No       
3         This car is british  Yes    Buy
4       This thing is british  Yes    Buy
```

Answer (score 1):

For example you can use `df.loc[]` ([see doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)):

```py
# condition
cond = (df1["Description"].str.contains('british')) & (df1["SUV?"] == "Yes")

# select rows by condidtion and insert value "buy"
df1.loc[cond, "Action"] = "buy"
```